# Troubles creating SOCKS + SSH VPN in C#

Tags: c#, networking, ssh, proxy, vpn

live in a country with heavy internet censorship and blocked websites. To bypass these restrictions, I purchased a VPS and connect to it using SSH through the command line using `ssh -p port -N -D 9999 user@ip` but this alone dosen't work so i have to use a program called [v2rayN](https://github.com/2dust/v2rayN) to make a SOCKS5 proxy with the config of `socks://Og==@127.0.0.1:9999` and when i put it on "Set System Proxy" it works like a VPN.

However, the problem is that i have to re-enter the cmd command really often because it leeps dissconnecting and as you can imagine this manual process becomes tiring, requiring me to re-enter the command and password each time.

To simplify this setup, I decided to create a simple app using Windows Form App to automate the process. Since I have a limited coding knowledge, I got assistance from ChatGPT to write most of the code. I have successfully automated the initial step of entering `ssh -p port -N -D 9999 user@ip` on the command line.

However, i need assistance with implementing the functionality of v2rayN into my own application. My goal is to use it without relying on v2rayN or any other external software. However, I'm unsure where to begin and since I have limited knowledge of coding and ChatGPT hasn't been very helpful, I've decided to come here to ask for assistance in the hopes that someone can guide me through the process.

Here are some important details about my application:

Packages used:

- Core.Renci.SshNet (version 2021.10.2)
- Newtonsoft.Json (version 13.0.3)
- Pcap.Net.x64 (version 1.0.4.1)
- Pcap.Net.x86 (version 1.0.4.1)
- PcapDotNet (version 0.10.2)
- Renci.SshNet.Async (version 1.4.0)
- SSH.NET (version 2020.0.2)

Framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Here's my current code for connecting:

```cs
private void ConnectPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string hostname = txtAddress.Text;
        int sshPort = int.Parse(txtPort.Text);
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        sshClient = new SshClient(hostname, sshPort, username, password);
        sshClient.Connect();
        
        // Start dynamic port forwarding
        int localPort = int.Parse(txtForwardPort.Text);
        portForwarding = new ForwardedPortDynamic("127.0.0.1", (uint)localPort);
        sshClient.AddForwardedPort(portForwarding);
        portForwarding.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions
    }
}
```

And here's my current code for disconnecting:

```cs
private void DisconnectPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    try
    {
        portForwarding?.Stop();
        sshClient?.Disconnect();
        sshClient?.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions
    }
}
```

the code is a lot more than this but this is the main connecting function if you need anything more please tell me

For those wondering why i just won't buy a vpn instead of using these, it's because normal vpns don't work here (the ip gets blocked after a while) otherwise i i wouldn't need to go to so many extra steps to fix the issue.

I would appreciate any assistance or advice, as well as any improvements or suggestions for the existing code. Thank you!

Comment: for your information, you could ask  or could have asked a superuser version of the question by asking chatGPT to write you a script..eg batch script or powershell script, rather than a C# program.  I know  somebody on superuser pushed you to ask on stackoverflow though.